# Datadog | Parsing logs with grok parser

Tags: datadog

I am trying to parse this logs using grok parser in datadog:

```
2022-04-26T08:10:17.545Z Finished activating shceme {"traceId":"xxxx","timestamp":"2022-05-01T14:39:57.340Z","payload":{"id":"xxx","name":"xxxx","description":"","featureType":"BOOLEAN","meterType":"None","unit":null,"units":null,"status":"NEW","type":"feature.created","webhooks":[]},"messageType":"FEATURE_CREATED"}
```

The rule I use:

```
ParsingRule %{notSpace:date} %{data:process_finished} %{data::json}
```

The result I expect:

```
 {
  "traceId": "xxxx",
  "timestamp": "2022-05-01T14:39:57.340Z",
  "messageType": "FEATURE_CREATED",
  "process_finished": "activating scheme",
  "date": "2022-04-26T08:10:17.545Z",
  "payload": {
    "status": "NEW",
    "featureType": "BOOLEAN",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "meterType": "None",
    "type": "feature.created",
    "id": "feature-analytics",
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

The result I get:

```
{
  "date": "2022-04-26T08:10:17.545Z",
  "process_started": "\u001bFinished"
}
```

does anyone knows what is wrong with my grok parsing rule?

Comment: `\u001b` presumably represents a byte with hexadecimal value `1B`, which would be the ASCII control character "Escape". So it looks like you've got some kind of non-text data in your log file which is messing up the parser.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the comment from IMSoP, you need to watch out for the encoded characters. However, I tried this with your example and it worked:

```
ParsingRule %{notSpace:date} %{regex("[^{]*"):process_finished} %{data::json}
```

*Side note from the doc: data: Matches any string including spaces and newlines. Equivalent to `.*` in regex. Use when none of above patterns is appropriate.*